# Connect Google Cloud Dataprep to AutoML Tables in Automated Pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

How are you to connect data preprocessing done with GCP Dataprep to and AutoML workflow?

Dataprep allows you a GUI to do some data preprocessing and exports a Dataflow recipes with your preprocessing tasks. Also, you can write out the data to an exported file back to GCS or BigQuery. However, how do you connect all the pieces so it is a part of a automated deployed AI Platform model?

The resulting multi-channel pipeline might look like this:
GCS -> Dataprep -> Dataflow -> BigQuery -> AutoML Tables -> Deployed Model

Answer (score 1):

There is a run job API available with the next release coming in September.